# creating a database in a client based program

Tags: c#, database, windows-services

we have developed a n application (like dropbox) in a meaning that it is monitoring a folder, when a file is created there it transfer it to the servers.
We are using some kind of temp files is order to keep information about former transfer and time, statuses and so on.  (basically like a database but with files for tables) - i don't like that.
Is there a library that can be used like database but without its process ? to use for a program like ours ? meaning to have a small database on a client computer ?
I think that `Sqlite` does that but i am not quite sure ?
Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact for such purpose.
Adding Entity Framework 4.0 will make you working just with strongly typed object. No need to write sql queries. EF will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite indeed sounds like what you want - it is purely file based, and does not require installing any server on the client machine.

Answer (score 0):

> We are using some kind of temp files is order to keep information
>   about former transfer and time, statuses and so on.

That looks like you are using log files. Instead of temp, I would use dedicated files for this purpose and I am absolutely fine with using files for this purpose, why don't you like that?

Still, there is [MS Office Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access), which keeps just a single file for a database, no services run, no installation required, easly accessible via [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171893%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Firebird embedded](http://www.firebirdsql.org) can do this with [dotnet drivers](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/)